# Broken hard drive

Tags: filesystems, disk, drive

about a week ago, I deleted all files from my hard drive using `rm -rf *` and `rm -rf .*`, thinking that all important files would be protected, but it seems like I was wrong.

After reboot, it wasn't able to mount the drive anymore.. I tried a couple more things to make it work (fill the disk with zeros, with the `dd` command), but I fear I only made things worse.

Now, lsblk command returns:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   3,9G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 448,6G  0 part /
└─sdb2   8:18   0  17,2G  0 part [SWAP]
```

The disk is supposed to be 1Tb, so there's a problem here. All of the partition or file system tools I tried get stuck when scanning the drive (I guess), including **sfdisk**, **wipefs**, **fsck**, and the gui KDE disk manager.

I'm under Manjaro, KDE, but that shouldn't be relevant...

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you delete the files? What things did you try that made it worse?

Comment: I can't recall for sure, but I think I deleted them with an `rm -rf *`, followed by a `rm -rf .*`, thinking that nothing important could get touched..

As for the things I tried, I launched a `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`, which never ended, so I forced it to stop, I think that wasn't that much of a good idea

Comment: Are there any other sd* drives in lsblk? They probably got reordered.

Comment: I added the full ouput of the __lsblk__ command to the original post.